# How to pass variable between routes flask?

Tags: flask

I have a problem with passing variables session between functions in flask:

```
@app.route('/anguis/periode/id', methods=['POST'])
def periode_id():
        session['id_pays'] = str(request.form['id_pays'])
...

@app.route('/anguis/mixitup')
def mixitup():
            id_pays = session.get('id_pays', None)
            periodeDebut = session.get('periodeDebut', None)
            periodeFin = session.get('periodeFin', None)
            Scursor.execute("SELECT * FROM PAYS where " + id_pays + ...)
```

The SQL request doesn't have result but when I replace id_pays with a value, it works.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Try id_pays = session['id_pays'] , sessions are saved so you shouldnt face a problem

Comment: thanks but this does'nt work for me and i don't understand why

Comment: I specify that i use ajax request in order to pass variable to my route flask. Is it the problem?

Comment: I found the solution, it was a SQL problem...:)